# How can i add controls to a gridview dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

I have two columns, how do i add a contro or two to each dynamically... each time a row is created..

I also want to create the columns dynamically.. through iteration.

How do i achieve that?

Comment: what do you mean by: - **I also want to create the columns dynamically.. through iteration.**?

Answer (score 5):

Place a `PlaceHolder` control in the column where you want to add control(s). Then inside [RowDataBound](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx&ei=sGkQTpmyKI-6-AaAlYXZDQ&usg=AFQjCNFLiXVmUYdeipjo17FOx0qggD2ZAw) event of the GridView add controls to the PlaceHolder

**Edit 1**

Your grid columns in aspx will look like this: -

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' ID="column1PlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' ID="column2PlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Your RowDataBound event will look like this: -

```
public void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (column1NeedsControls)
    {
        PlaceHolder placeHolder = e.Row.FindControl("column1PlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder;
        TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
    }

    if (column2NeedsControls)
    {
        PlaceHolder placeHolder = e.Row.FindControl("column2PlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder;
        TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So with each row there will be a text box added. I have two columns, however, how do I know what to place in what...i want to place 2 controls in one column..and another control in another

Comment: you can call `placeHolder.Controls.Add` method to add as many controls as you want. Similarly, if you have two columns then you have to place a place holder in each column (obviously having two diferent ids) and have to do the same work with that.

Comment: But how do u access to the second column or the first column..The event is triggered when any row is added..Why do I need the event/?..how do i trigger it

Comment: lol..there is no solution to this..i cant add controls to two different columns

Comment: :) nothing is impossible, don't worry.